# V-if vs Lazy loading component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, lazy-loading

I'm starting to learn Vue.js and I can not understand the difference between v-if and lazy loading in terms of performance and speed for the whole application.

so let's say I have this:

```
<template>
  <div class="popup" v-if="popUp">
    <pop-up :msg="hello" />
  </div>
</template>
```

so my question is, the popup component won't be rendered/downloaded by the browser(?) until the condition is met. if so what's the point of using the lazy loading technique?

Comment: The component will be downloaded by the browser right away, it simply won't be rendered. With lazy loading the component won't be downloaded right away, but will incur a small delay once the component actually needs to be loaded.

Comment: ah, I see. tbh I thought that if a component gets downloaded but not rendered does not make much differenct in terms of performance. I was wrong...